# Is there any correlation between $A^B$ and $B^A$?

Tags: relations, exponentiation, noncommutative-algebra

So, we all know that exponentiation is non-commutative, but is there any relationship despite exponentiation's not being commutative? Is there any correlation between $A^B$ and $B^A$ where $A$ and $B$ are real numbers?

Comment: What type of objects are $A$ and $B$?  Also, what do you count as a 'relationship'?

Comment: By relationship, I simply mean a way to get from one to the other.. For example, $log(100)=2$ & $10^2=100$.

Comment: My previous example was a bit of a bad example.. More of what I mean is how $\pi = ((log_{-1}e)i)^{-1}$.

Comment: Do you mean "correlation" in a statistical sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no function $f$ such that $f(A^B)=B^A$ (for all real numbers $A,B$ such that $A^B$ and $B^A$ are defined). If there *were* such a function $f$, then for example we would have $$36=6^2=f(2^6)=f(4^3)=3^4=81,$$ which is clearly not the case.

Now, for any positive $A\neq 1$, there *is* a function $f_A$ such that $f_A(A^B)=B^A$ for any $B$. In particular, $$f_A(x):=\left(\frac{\log x}{\log A}\right)^A.$$ Also, for any positive $B$, there is a function $g_B$ such that $g_B(A^B)=B^A$ for any $A$. In particular, $$g_B(x):=B^{\frac{\log x}{B}}.$$

Comment: (+1) I think you required that such a function would be bijective in the first contradiction.

Comment: @user1709828: Actually, there's no need for that. Since $2^6=64=4^3$, then the equality in the very middle of the chain would necessarily hold if $f$ were a function. The two equalities on the ends are just rewrites, and the last two equalities would hold if the function $f$ did what we wanted it to do. What I *really* showed is that no such function exists, bijective or otherwise.

Comment: ah, yes, sorry. my bad.

Comment: Quite all right.